# Prove that the function $f(x) = (1-x)/(1+x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $(-1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the function $$f(x) = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$$ is not uniformly continuous on $(-1,\infty)$.

I was able to prove uniform continuity on $[0,\infty)$, but I'm not sure how to disprove it :S

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to-1^+}\frac{1-x}{1+x}=+\infty $$
and thus it can't be uniform continue. Indeed, if it's uniform continue on $(-1,r]$ for $r>-1$, then $\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)$ exist, and thus if $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ doesn't exist, it can't be uniform continue. To prove the claim, suppose that $f:]a,b]\to\mathbb R$ uniform continue, and let $(a_n)$ a sequence that converge to $a$. Then, $(a_n)$ is a cauchy sequence, and in particular, 
$$|f(a_n)-f(a_n)|<|a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon$$
if $n,m>N$ for an certain $N\in\mathbb N$ and all $\varepsilon>0$. Therefore $(f(a_n))$ is also a Cauchy sequence and thus it converge. Now you can prove that if $(f(a_n))$ converge for all $(a_n)$ such that $a_n\to a$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exist what proove the claim.